# Is it possible to access a STL deque element by its address?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl

Good afternoon , We are trying to make a simple emulation of the Windows memory mapped caching subsystem. We are using several STL data structures.

1. A STL deque , `std::deque<Range>` accesses, which holds and records information about the last recently used to the most recently used  memory mapped regions.
2. A STL set, `std::set<char *>` ranges_pointer which might hold pointers to the elements in the STL `deque`..

Basically, when we retrieve a pointer to a valid memory mapped region from the STL set , we would like to use that pointer to direcly access the corresponding element deque in O(constant time). Then, we would like to move that deque element to the front of the STL deque so that that subsequent reguests for clusters of memory mapped addreses can be found at the front of the STL deque accesses.

We know from Stack Overflow that the only STL container that guarantees contingous addresses is STL vector. However, every time one moves a element from a STL vector, it takes O(linear) time to shift or memcpy the remaining items into the right location,This could be expensive. In contrast, when you move a element from STL deque, all one has to rearrange the next and prev pointers on both sides of the element that is moved.

We were wondering if one could write a method to access a STL deque element by its address. Although the std::allocator does not guarantee contiguous STL deque adresses, perhaps we could use a custom memory pool allocator to get a chunk of contiguous addresses.

Also, do BOOST or other C++ frameworks implement contiguous doubly linked lists which offer random access just like  STL deque. The class Range holds all the essential information about every cached memory mapped region, The class Range is stored in the the std::deque accessess member variable. Thank you. The class Range is shown below:

```
class Range { 
     public:   
         explicit Range(int item){
            mLow = item;
            mHigh = item;
            mPtr  = 0;
            mMapPtr = 0;
         }
         Range(int low, int high, char* ptr = 0,char* mapptr = 0,  
               int currMappedLength = 0){  
            mLow = low;
            mHigh = high;
            mPtr  = ptr;
            mMapPtr = mapptr;
            mMappedLength = currMappedLength;       
         }
         Range(void){  
            mLow = 0;
            mHigh = 0;
            mPtr  = 0;
            mMapPtr = 0;
         }


         ~Range(){
         }

         bool operator<(const Range& rhs) const{
                return mHigh < rhs.mHigh;
         } 
         int low() const { return mLow; }   
         int high() const { return mHigh; }
         char* getMapPtr() const { return mMapPtr; }
         int getMappedLength() const { return mMappedLength; }
     private:   
         int mLow;   // beginning of memory mapped region
         int mHigh;  // end of memory mapped region 
         char* mMapPtr; // return value from MapViewOfFile
         int mMappedLength; // length of memory mapped region
}; // class Range
```

Comment: The term "contiguous doubly linked list" doesn't make sense. If memory was contiguous, you wouldn't need the links between nodes.

Comment: interjay, You are correct, I apologize for the use of the term. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: You have a misconception of what a deque does... it takes linear time on the minimum of the distances from the removed element to the first or last element. If you want to remove elements from the middle, and that is a common operation, don't use a deque

Comment: @David Rodriguez, If one uses binary search and the std::deque random access operator[], theoretcallyit takes 0(logarithmic time) to find the iteration location to remove or insert an element. However, it takes  0(linear time) to find the std::list iterator   location to remove from or insert or unless one uses something like skip lists. Does STL or Boost offer any variants of the STL List that are faster than O(linear time) for removing or inserting elements. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @David Rodriguez, The Silicon Graphics STL documentation says it takes O(linear time) to insert or remove from the middle of a deque. Is this because STL deque maintains a separate array of pointers to the doubly linked elements in STL deque? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: An implementation using fixed sized blocks linked in a list cannot fulfill the `O(1)` indexing requirement: as the container grows the number of links to be traversed would increase linearly (divided by a factor). `deque` are usually implemented in terms similar to a `vector` of `vector`, rather than a `list` of `vector`. I am not sure on where you are getting your information from, but the costs that you are producing are not those of the standard containers. Removal of an element from the middle of a list is a `O(1)` operation (while *locating* the object to remove is `O(N)`)

Comment: It takes linear time to insert or remove from the middle of a `deque` because all of the objects from the deleted position to the end (or the beginning if that is shorter) have to be *moved in* (compacting). Similarly for insertion, to allocate space for the new element, all of the rest of the elements to the beginning or the end (whichever is shorter) have to be *moved out* (expanding), and then the new space is filled with the new element. The datum you produce from SGI is a more general description of what I said in my comment, and what is present in the standard in §23.2.1.2.

Comment: @David Rodridguez, Thank you for reply.When I say that it takes 0(linear time) to insert or remove elements from the middle of a list. I am including the time it takes to locating the object to remove. If it takes 0(linear) time to insert or remove from the middle of a dequeue, then what are the objects that have to be moved in or out, The deque using a doubly linked list. It shouldn't O(linear time) to rearrange the pointers used in remove & insert. So are the obects you moving in and out in the array of pointers to the doubly linked elements? Thank you.

Comment: @Interjay, We have looked at several C++ custom STL allocators. They all say custom allocators should not be used with std::vector or std::deque. Is there a reason custom STL allocators cannot be used with std::deque? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: First things first: a `deque` using a linked list would not be standard conforming: it would not meet the requirement of random access container (lookup with `operator[]` in constant time `O(1)`). Next: complexity requirements hide *factors* out, and it is important to know what they mean or you will be mixing apples and bananas. The operation *delete the n-th element* on a list requires `O(N)` time to lookup the element and `O(1)` to remove, and the equivalent operation on a deque requires `O(1)` for the lookup and `O'(N)` for the removal, so you might think that they are equivalent.

Comment: But they are not. Lookup in a list requires `O(N)` operations, each one is *compare index, if not the one, advance pointer*, so the cost is a linear number of pointer updates and integer comparisons. On the other hand, removing an element from the middle of a deque requires `O'(N)` operations each of which is *copy the contained element*. Now imagine that each element itself is not a single datum, but a vector of average length M, then the operation takes `O(N * M)` N copies of M elements.

Comment: I am quite curious where you get the information from, and you might consider changing the sources, since there is no reason not to use allocators with vectors and lists in general, so either the information is bogus or you have missed the important bit of information: why in that particular case you are being advised not to use allocators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using a `set` to hold the addresses, how about a `map` that contains the address and an iterator into the `deque`?

Note that moving an element from the middle of a deque to the beginning or end is going to be no faster than doing it for a vector. You might want to think about using a `list`.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, Thank you for your answer. If we use a STL map that contains the address and an iterator into the deque, THe iterator may not be accurate after a few deque insertions and several deque erases and push_front. We thought about using a list but it is singly linked altough it may be contiguos. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank, I keep forgetting the conditions for iterator invalidation on a deque, I don't use it often enough. I'm not sure why you want contiguous layout for your container, can you explain a little?

Comment: @Mark Ransom, We think your STL map solution is excellent but we don't know what will happen to the dequeue iterator stored in STL map after a few deque insertions. Is there a way to preserve the validity of the STL deque iterator? The reason we would want contiguous layout for a container is so that we can can use  pointer arithmetic to access a particular element in a STL container by its address. But, after reading your idea, iterators could be be elegant if their validity can be ensured. Thank you,

Comment: @Mark Ransom, We found out the conditions for iterator invalidation on a deque: Following is the excerpts from -- The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference, By Nicolai M. Josuttis 

Any insertion or deletion of elements other than at the beginning or end invalidates all pointers, references, and iterators that refer to elements of the deque.

Thank you for your answer,

Comment: @Mark Ransom, We just found that that the STL list iterator can stay valid after an insertion or deletion. Here is the quote: Lists have the property that insertion and splicing do not invalidate iterators to list elements, and that even removal invalidates only the iterators that point to the elements that are removed. The ordering of iterators may be changed  but the iterators themselves will not be invalidated  unless that invalidation or mutation is explicit.We understand why you suggested STL list instead of map. Deque offers random access but List does not. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, In our protype, we do a significant number of insertions into the STL containers deque and set. Because std::deque has random access , we can do a binary search before inserting an element into std::deque. However, since STL list does not have a random access operator, we cannot do binary search on a STL list before insert, Therefore it takes O(linear time) to insert into a STL list. We know that that skip list is faster than STL list when it comes to inserting, But where do we find a STL implementation of Skip List? THank you for your help.